# Spring @Cacheable : need to know value return from cache or not

Tags: java, spring, spring-aop, spring-cache

Our applications using Spring Cache and need to know if response was returned from cache OR it was actually calculated. We are looking to add a flag in result HashMap that will indicate it. However whatever is returned by method, it is cached so not sure if we can do it in calculate method implementation.
Is there any way to know if calculate method was executed OR return value coming from cache when calling calculate method?

Code we are using for calculate method -

```
@Cacheable(
        cacheNames = "request",
        key = "#cacheMapKey",           
        unless = "#result['ErrorMessage'] != null")
public Map<String, Object> calculate(Map<String, Object> cacheMapKey, Map<String, Object> message) {
    //method implementation
     return result;
}
```

Comment: Why? Why would you need to know where it comes from?

Comment: Well, you _could_ add some interceptor etc. but you'd have to put the information into the returned object anyway, otherwise how would you get it? Also, as M. Deinum already stated, do you _really_ need to know it was calculated or retrieved from a cache? The only thing I could imagine that might make sense here is to know the age of the data - that could be solved by setting a timestamp in the object that indicates when calculation took place. Whether a newly calculated object would then be retrieved from cache or not would be next to irrelevant.

Comment: When data is returned from Cache then users want to know that it is from cache, not real time.

Comment: You can just add a method which will add something to the map or invalidate the cache completely and change a flag to false. Then when you call the calculation method it will recache the result and change that flag to true. Log the flag on both methods and this how you can verify that the cache gets updated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With a little extra work, it is rather simple to add a bit of state to your `@Cacheable` component service methods.

I use this technique when I am answering SO questions like this to show that the value came from the cache vs. the service method by actually computing the value. For [example](https://github.com/jxblum/stackoverflow-questions-answers/blob/master/spring-cache/src/test/java/io/stackoverflow/questions/spring/cache/SimpleCacheKeyIntegrationTests.java#L140).

You will notice this `@Cacheable`, `@Service` class [extends](https://github.com/jxblum/stackoverflow-questions-answers/blob/master/spring-cache/src/test/java/io/stackoverflow/questions/spring/cache/SimpleCacheKeyIntegrationTests.java#L135-L136) an abstract base class ([`CacheableService`](https://github.com/jxblum/stackoverflow-questions-answers/blob/master/spring-core/src/main/java/org/springframework/cache/CacheableService.java)) to help manage the "cacheable" state. That way, multiple `@Cacheable`, `@Service` classes can utilize this functionality if need be.

The `CacheableService` class contains methods to query the state of the cache operation, like [`isCacheMiss()`](https://github.com/jxblum/stackoverflow-questions-answers/blob/master/spring-core/src/main/java/org/springframework/cache/CacheableService.java#L36-L38) and [`isCacheHit()`](https://github.com/jxblum/stackoverflow-questions-answers/blob/master/spring-core/src/main/java/org/springframework/cache/CacheableService.java#L32-L34). Inside the `@Cacheable` methods, when invoked due to a "cache miss", is where you would set this bit, by calling [`setCacheMiss()`](https://github.com/jxblum/stackoverflow-questions-answers/blob/master/spring-core/src/main/java/org/springframework/cache/CacheableService.java#L40-L42).  Again, the `setCacheMiss()` method is [called like so](https://github.com/jxblum/stackoverflow-questions-answers/blob/master/spring-cache/src/test/java/io/stackoverflow/questions/spring/cache/SimpleCacheKeyIntegrationTests.java#L140), inside your `@Cacheable` service [method](https://github.com/jxblum/stackoverflow-questions-answers/blob/master/spring-cache/src/test/java/io/stackoverflow/questions/spring/cache/SimpleCacheKeyIntegrationTests.java#L138-L142).

However, a few words of caution!

First, while the abstract `CacheableService` class [manages the state](https://github.com/jxblum/stackoverflow-questions-answers/blob/master/spring-core/src/main/java/org/springframework/cache/CacheableService.java#L30) of the `cacheMiss` bit with a Thread-safe class (i.e. `AtomicBoolean`), the `CacheableService` class itself is **not** Thread-safe when used in a highly concurrent environment when you have multiple `@Cacheable` service methods setting the `cacheMiss` bit.

That is, if you have a component class with multiple `@Cacheable` service methods all setting the `cacheMiss` bit using `setCacheMiss()` in a multi-Threaded environment (which is especially `true` in a Web application) then it is possible to read stale state of `cacheMiss` when querying the bit. Meaning, the `cacheMiss` bit could be `true` or `false` depending on the state of the cache, the operation called and the interleaving of Threads. Therefore, more work is needed in this case, so be careful if you are relying on the state of the `cacheMiss` bit for critical decisions.

Second, this approach, using an abstract `CacheableService` class, does not work for *Spring Data* (CRUD) *Repositories* based on an interface. As others have mentioned in the comments, you could encapsulate this caching logic in an AOP Advice and intercept the appropriate calls, in this case. Personally, I prefer that caching, security, transactions, etc, all be managed in the Service layer of the application rather than the Data Access layer.

Finally, there are undoubtedly other limitations you might run into, as the example code I have provided above was never meant for production, only demonstration purposes. I leave it to you as an exercise to figure out how to mold these bits for your needs.